# AWK command working in bash but not in shell script

Tags: awk, sh

I am trying to append a new column to a csv file using awk. The command is working fine in bash but when I want to run it in a shell script, I am getting "invalid char '▒' in expression" and "syntax error".

Here is the command:
`awk -v d="100" -F"," 'FNR==1{​​​a="Pmax"}​​​​​​​​​​ FNR>1{​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​a=d}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ {​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​print $0","a}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​' input.csv > temp.csv`

The issue seems to occurs because of the awk a variable that I am using in my FNR if condition.

Any ideas to help me? I already tried to declare a using -v a="NULL" but it is sending me back an invalid variable name error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like whatever tool you used to create the script added a weird character. Or maybe there's something else in the script. You'd have to show us the complete script and the complete error messages for us to be able to help you more. And don't cram your script all into a single line so when you get an error message it can pinpoint where in your code the problem occurs.

Comment: Try running `od -c` or similar on your script to see which characters it really contains.

Comment: the code in your question contains zero-width spaces

Answer (score 0):

To confirm the comments you received under your question, this is what the script in your question looks like when copy/pasted into `vi`:

```
awk -v d="100" -F"," 'FNR==1{<200b><200b><200b>a="Pmax"}<200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b> FNR>1{<200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b>a=d}<200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b> {<200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b>print $0","a}<200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b><200b>' input.csv > temp.csv
```

See https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm

By the way, not related to your problem but your script should be written as

```
awk -v d='100' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $0 (NR>1 ? d : "Pmax")}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​' input.csv > temp.csv
```

for conciseness.

---

Some other ways to see the undesirable characters:

```
$ cat -A file
awk -v d="100" -F"," 'FNR==1{M-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^Ka="Pmax"}M-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^K FNR>1{M-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^Ka=d}M-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^K {M-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^Kprint $0","a}M-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^KM-bM-^@M-^K' input.csv > temp.csv
```

```
$ od -c file
0000000   a   w   k       -   v       d   =   "   1   0   0   "       -
0000020   F   "   ,   "       '   F   N   R   =   =   1   { 342 200 213
0000040 342 200 213 342 200 213   a   =   "   P   m   a   x   "   } 342
0000060 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200
0000100 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213       F   N
0000120   R   >   1   { 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213
0000140 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342
0000160 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200
0000200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213
0000220 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342
0000240 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200
0000260 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213
0000300 342 200 213 342 200 213   a   =   d   } 342 200 213 342 200 213
0000320 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342
0000340 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200
0000360 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213
0000400 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342
0000420 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200
0000440 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213
0000460 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342
0000500 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200
0000520 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213
0000540 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342
0000560 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200
0000600 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213
0000620       { 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200
0000640 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213
0000660 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342
0000700 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200
0000720 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213
0000740 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342
0000760 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200
0001000 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213
0001020 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342
0001040 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200
0001060 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213
0001100 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342
0001120 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213   p   r   i   n   t       $   0
0001140   "   ,   "   a   } 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200
0001160 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213
0001200 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342
0001220 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200
0001240 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213
0001260 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342
0001300 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200
0001320 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213
0001340 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342
0001360 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200
0001400 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213
0001420 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342
0001440 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213 342 200 213   '       i   n   p
0001460   u   t   .   c   s   v       >       t   e   m   p   .   c   s
0001500   v
0001501
```